# Parsing mathematical equation in Java

Tags: java, parsing, math, integer-arithmetic

I want to use interval arithmetic to calculate range of a given equation. For example, C = f(A, B) where

```
f = -12.5 * log10 ( 1 + ( 0.64*( 1-cos(A) )/( 1-cos(B/4) ))
```

I would give range of A and B as input and a String which contains f. The interval arithmetic library I have computes ranges for simple functions like f = log A etc. So to compute the range for above function, I have to manually write multiple steps, like first find cos(A), then 1 - cos(A) and so on till I get the range for whole equation. I'm trying to find if there is a way to parse this equation, probably get the steps computed during computation by a parser, so that at every step, I can find a range and let the parser go to the next step.

To be more clear, I want to know each step during the evaluation of expression.For example, if f = A + B (1-C). Software calculates 1-c first, then it will calculate B * (1-C), then it will add it to A. So, I need control at every step, so that I can find range for the expression evaluated so far.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: There's probably an implementation you can borrow of a [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). That should get you started to the point where you can evaluate most of the expression.

Comment: you might check out [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org)

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to do it like this:

```
import javax.script.*;


ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
try {
     // evaluate JavaScript code for evaluating formulas
     Object result = engine.eval(formula);
     System.out.println(result);
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong. Was your syntax invalid?");
}
```

Note that `log10` must be replaced with `Math.log10`, and the assignment operator must be removed. That should not be too hard to implement, something like

```
String formula = input.substring(intput.indexOf("=") + 1).replace("log10","Math.log10").replace("cos","Math.cos");
```

Comment: thank you for the input. But I want to know to know each step during the evaluation of expression.For example, if f = A + B (1-C). Software calculate 1-c first, then it will calculate B * (1-C), then it will add it to A. So, I need control at every step, so that I can find range for the expression evaluated so far. Please let me know if I'm clear.

Comment: Yes, you are clear. I agree with David Ehrmann, the shunting yard algorithm would be best for this. You might want to edit the question.